# Open a View that is not the root one and keep the tabbarcontroller from the root view (swift)

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, rootview

Hi guys I have an application with a view organization like the picture bellow:

Views:
[image]

My Application has to open View B (from the picture) when an user opens an attachment (I have another question [Open specific view when user opens an attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35214006/how-to-open-in-a-ios-app-a-specific-view-based-on-a-file-extension-that-an-user) which I have found the answer for this question). I have done that already my problem is that when I open View B the tabbar is not present.

Is there a way that when I open View B I see the tabbar that is part of the root view??

**Update:** 
Here is the code that I use to open the view from the **AppDelegate.swift file**:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AddComment") as! AddCommentViewController
    window?.rootViewController = vc 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just saw your updated post. In order for this to work, the following has to be true:

1. `window?.rootViewController` is a UITabBarController
2. The view controller at `indexOfNavigationViewControllerInTabBar` in the tab bar is a UINavigationViewController.

If so, then do:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    let indexOfNavigationViewControllerInTabBar = 0 // Set yourself
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AddComment") as! AddCommentViewController
    let tabBarController = window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    let navigationController = tabBarController.viewControllers![indexOfNavigationViewControllerInTabBar] as! UINavigationController
    navigationController.setViewControllers([vc], animated: true)
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = indexOfNavigationViewControllerInTabBar
}
```